# Separate File for Theming an Xcode Project

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, xcode5

Just like to ask on how i could create a separate file (something like a css) that i can just "include" to all of my uiviewcontrollers? I have a tabviewcontroller with 3 uiviewcontrollers attached to it. I know i can declare it on viewDidLoad to change the tints, backgrounds and such. But copying them to each controllers would be messy and every time i would change it i need to do the same thing to all.

I have xcode5 and ios7 only project.

already created firstabvc, secondtabvc, and thirdtabvc associated on uivc on storyboard. I'm thinking of creating a new file for the "CustomTheme", what subclass should it be and how i can include them to the 3 vc? thanks!

Comment: thank you so much for the link. I don't literally meant "css", just the common/natural way on how to do it? o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use CSS, search for pixate.

If you want to use built in features, look at the [`UIAppearance`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) [proxy](http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/).